# rabbitmq + spring boot + consumers idle for 15 mins after processing a single message

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, pcf

We use spring boot (1.5) and integration to connect to Rabbit MQ as a service on PCF

Properties set
 - concurrency = 15
 - maxConcurrency = 25
 - default prefetch and txSize.

How the message are processed.

1. The queue received 26 messages within less than 1 sec.
2. 15 consumers started and completed with the next minute.
3. Average time taken by each consumer is 30 secs approx.
4. Few consumers took less than 15 secs.
5. As each consumer acknowledged, new messages(16th, 17th message) from ready becomes unacknowledged on rabbit MQ.

So far as expected, since i assume new messages are being proccessed as old messages are acknowledged.
But as new messages become unack'ed on rabbitMQ, they are not processed by any consumers. Consumers are stuck and idle.

1. This continues and all ready state messages become unacknowledged and stay there without any activity.
2. They all resume after approx 15mins.

I see this behavior always.

Any guidance ?

Here is the code that does wiring of rabbit MQ
The MessageHandler in between has code that connects to big data and does some querying.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMQ {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.concurrency:3}")
    private int concurrentConsumers;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.maxConcurrency:5}")
    private int maxConcurrentConsumers;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.max-attempts:3}")
    private int maxAttempts;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.initial-interval:2000}")
    private int initialInterval;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.multiplier:3}")
    private int multiplier;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.max-interval:10000}")
    private int maxInterval;

    @Autowired
    private BotQueues botQueues;

    @Autowired
    private RetryFailLogger retryRecoverer;

    @Bean
    public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
                .backOffOptions(initialInterval, multiplier, maxInterval) // initialInterval, multiplier, maxInterval
                .maxAttempts(maxAttempts)
                .messageKeyGenerator(message -> message.getMessageProperties().getMessageId())
                .recoverer(retryRecoverer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter defaultJsonMessageConverter() {

        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        classMapper.setDefaultType(JobDetailInfo.class);
        jsonConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);

        return jsonConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
            throws BeansException, ClassNotFoundException {

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(botQueues.inputQueues());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] {statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor()});
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inbound(SimpleMessageListenerContainer container,
            @Qualifier("commonInputChannel") MessageChannel amqpInputChannel) {
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(container);
        adapter.setMessageConverter(defaultJsonMessageConverter());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(amqpInputChannel);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "commonInputChannel", outputChannel = "commonOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler();
    }

    @Router(inputChannel = "commonOutputChannel")
    public String resolveJobChannel(JobDetailInfo jobDetailInfo) {

        String returnChannel = "";

        if (jobDetailInfo != null) {
            switch (jobDetailInfo.getJobStatus()) {
                case Scheduled:
                    returnChannel = "collectorChannel";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return returnChannel;
    }
}
```

**Thread Dump:**

> {"threadName":"container-14","threadId":40,"blockedTime":-1,"blockedCount":45,"waitedTime":-1,"waitedCount":66654,"lockName":"java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@1b4302a9","lockOwnerId":-1,"lockOwnerName":null,"inNative":false,"suspended":false,"threadState":"TIMED_WAITING","stackTrace":[{"methodName":"park","fileName":"Unsafe.java","lineNumber":-2,"className":"sun.misc.Unsafe","nativeMethod":true},{"methodName":"parkNanos","fileName":"LockSupport.java","lineNumber":215,"className":"java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"awaitNanos","fileName":"AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java","lineNumber":2078,"className":"java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"poll","fileName":"LinkedBlockingQueue.java","lineNumber":467,"className":"java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"nextMessage","fileName":"BlockingQueueConsumer.java","lineNumber":461,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doReceiveAndExecute","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1214,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"receiveAndExecute","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1189,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"access$1500","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":97,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1421,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":748,"className":"java.lang.Thread","nativeMethod":false}],"lockedMonitors":[],"lockedSynchronizers":[],"lockInfo":{"className":"java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject","identityHashCode":457376425}},
>
> {"threadName":"container-13","threadId":39,"blockedTime":-1,"blockedCount":34,"waitedTime":-1,"waitedCount":66160,"lockName":null,"lockOwnerId":-1,"lockOwnerName":null,"inNative":true,"suspended":false,"threadState":"RUNNABLE","stackTrace":[{"methodName":"socketRead0","fileName":"SocketInputStream.java","lineNumber":-2,"className":"java.net.SocketInputStream","nativeMethod":true},{"methodName":"socketRead","fileName":"SocketInputStream.java","lineNumber":116,"className":"java.net.SocketInputStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"read","fileName":"SocketInputStream.java","lineNumber":171,"className":"java.net.SocketInputStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"read","fileName":"SocketInputStream.java","lineNumber":141,"className":"java.net.SocketInputStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"readMore","fileName":"VisibleBufferedInputStream.java","lineNumber":140,"className":"org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"ensureBytes","fileName":"VisibleBufferedInputStream.java","lineNumber":109,"className":"org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"read","fileName":"VisibleBufferedInputStream.java","lineNumber":67,"className":"org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"receiveChar","fileName":"PGStream.java","lineNumber":280,"className":"org.postgresql.core.PGStream","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"processResults","fileName":"QueryExecutorImpl.java","lineNumber":1916,"className":"org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"QueryExecutorImpl.java","lineNumber":288,"className":"org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"executeInternal","fileName":"PgStatement.java","lineNumber":430,"className":"org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"PgStatement.java","lineNumber":356,"className":"org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"executeWithFlags","fileName":"PgStatement.java","lineNumber":303,"className":"org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"executeCachedSql","fileName":"PgStatement.java","lineNumber":289,"className":"org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"executeWithFlags","fileName":"PgStatement.java","lineNumber":266,"className":"org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"PgStatement.java","lineNumber":262,"className":"org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"validate","fileName":"PooledConnection.java","lineNumber":532,"className":"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"validate","fileName":"PooledConnection.java","lineNumber":443,"className":"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"borrowConnection","fileName":"ConnectionPool.java","lineNumber":802,"className":"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"borrowConnection","fileName":"ConnectionPool.java","lineNumber":651,"className":"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getConnection","fileName":"ConnectionPool.java","lineNumber":198,"className":"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getConnection","fileName":"DataSourceProxy.java","lineNumber":132,"className":"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getConnection","fileName":"DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java","lineNumber":122,"className":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"obtainConnection","fileName":"NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java","lineNumber":35,"className":"org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"acquireConnectionIfNeeded","fileName":"LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java","lineNumber":99,"className":"org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getPhysicalConnection","fileName":"LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java","lineNumber":129,"className":"org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getConnectionForTransactionManagement","fileName":"LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java","lineNumber":247,"className":"org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"begin","fileName":"LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java","lineNumber":254,"className":"org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"begin","fileName":"JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java","lineNumber":203,"className":"org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"begin","fileName":"TransactionImpl.java","lineNumber":56,"className":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"beginTransaction","fileName":"HibernateJpaDialect.java","lineNumber":189,"className":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doBegin","fileName":"JpaTransactionManager.java","lineNumber":380,"className":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getTransaction","fileName":"AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java","lineNumber":373,"className":"org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"createTransactionIfNecessary","fileName":"TransactionAspectSupport.java","lineNumber":447,"className":"org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeWithinTransaction","fileName":"TransactionAspectSupport.java","lineNumber":277,"className":"org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"TransactionInterceptor.java","lineNumber":96,"className":"org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"proceed","fileName":"ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java","lineNumber":179,"className":"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"intercept","fileName":"CglibAopProxy.java","lineNumber":673,"className":"org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"handleMessage","fileName":"","lineNumber":-1,"className":"message.handlers.MessageHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf53d23e","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":43,"className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"Method.java","lineNumber":498,"className":"java.lang.reflect.Method","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java","lineNumber":113,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getValueInternal","fileName":"MethodReference.java","lineNumber":102,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"access$000","fileName":"MethodReference.java","lineNumber":49,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getValue","fileName":"MethodReference.java","lineNumber":347,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getValueInternal","fileName":"CompoundExpression.java","lineNumber":88,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getTypedValue","fileName":"SpelNodeImpl.java","lineNumber":131,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getValue","fileName":"SpelExpression.java","lineNumber":330,"className":"org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"evaluateExpression","fileName":"AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java","lineNumber":169,"className":"org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"processInternal","fileName":"MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java","lineNumber":319,"className":"org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"process","fileName":"MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java","lineNumber":155,"className":"org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"processMessage","fileName":"MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java","lineNumber":93,"className":"org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"handleRequestMessage","fileName":"ServiceActivatingHandler.java","lineNumber":89,"className":"org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"handleMessageInternal","fileName":"AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java","lineNumber":109,"className":"org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"handleMessage","fileName":"AbstractMessageHandler.java","lineNumber":127,"className":"org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doDispatch","fileName":"UnicastingDispatcher.java","lineNumber":160,"className":"org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"dispatch","fileName":"UnicastingDispatcher.java","lineNumber":121,"className":"org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doSend","fileName":"AbstractSubscribableChannel.java","lineNumber":89,"className":"org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"send","fileName":"AbstractMessageChannel.java","lineNumber":423,"className":"org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"send","fileName":"AbstractMessageChannel.java","lineNumber":373,"className":"org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doSend","fileName":"GenericMessagingTemplate.java","lineNumber":115,"className":"org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doSend","fileName":"GenericMessagingTemplate.java","lineNumber":45,"className":"org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"send","fileName":"AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java","lineNumber":105,"className":"org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"sendMessage","fileName":"MessageProducerSupport.java","lineNumber":188,"className":"org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"access$1100","fileName":"AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java","lineNumber":56,"className":"org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"processMessage","fileName":"AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java","lineNumber":246,"className":"org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"onMessage","fileName":"AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java","lineNumber":203,"className":"org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doInvokeListener","fileName":"AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":822,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeListener","fileName":"AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":745,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"access$001","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":97,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeListener","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":189,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":43,"className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"Method.java","lineNumber":498,"className":"java.lang.reflect.Method","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeJoinpointUsingReflection","fileName":"AopUtils.java","lineNumber":333,"className":"org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeJoinpoint","fileName":"ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java","lineNumber":190,"className":"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"proceed","fileName":"ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java","lineNumber":157,"className":"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doWithRetry","fileName":"StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java","lineNumber":229,"className":"org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor$MethodInvocationRetryCallback","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doExecute","fileName":"RetryTemplate.java","lineNumber":286,"className":"org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"RetryTemplate.java","lineNumber":210,"className":"org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java","lineNumber":173,"className":"org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"proceed","fileName":"ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java","lineNumber":179,"className":"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"JdkDynamicAopProxy.java","lineNumber":213,"className":"org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeListener","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeListener","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1276,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"executeListener","fileName":"AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":726,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doReceiveAndExecute","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1219,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"receiveAndExecute","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1189,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"access$1500","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":97,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java","lineNumber":1421,"className":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":748,"className":"java.lang.Thread","nativeMethod":false}],"lockedMonitors":[{"className":"org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl","identityHashCode":1428002949,"lockedStackDepth":9,"lockedStackFrame":{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"QueryExecutorImpl.java","lineNumber":288,"className":"org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl","nativeMethod":false}}],"lockedSynchronizers":[{"className":"java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync","identityHashCode":1110565932}],"lockInfo":null}

Comment: can u copy&paste the code you are using?

Comment: added code. let me know if you see anything missing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would see that behavior; in most cases (in my experience) such issues are caused by the listener thread "stuck" in user code. It's not possible for a consumer thread to be "idle" in that way; and in any case, it wouldn't restart 15 minutes later.

Next step (for me) would be to take a thread dump to see what the threads are doing. Boot provides the `/dump` endpoint to do that if you can't use jstack or VisualVM.

Comment: Gary, i have seen your other [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/724928-consumers-stops-consuming-no-exception-or-warnings) on heartbeats which we plan to try.

Comment: But, since the messages are unack'ed i doubt if thats the right direction.

Comment: I got the thread dump when the issue occured. Will that be helpful ?

Comment: It will if you post ir somewhere.

Comment: These sites are blocked for us. So i have placed thread dump for two container threads (13 and 14) in my original post.  Let me know if that helps. From the dump, i assume container - 13 seems problematic since it just processed a message and could not take the next message, but container-14 did not pick any message yet.

Comment: Right; #13 is busy processing a message #14 is idle; it's hard for me to speculate without the whole picture (container configuration and full thread dump), but I suspect everything is working properly in the framework and your issues are with your code.